# API response time takes long time

Tags: json, swift, api, networking

I make an API call. Usually it loads instantly. But when I open the app after few hours it takes too long to load the API data (around 10-20 seconds). When I get the initial data successfully, other requests loads instantly.

Here is my code:

```
func fetchJSON<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T?, Error?) -> ()) {
            
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, resp, err) in
        if let err = err {
            completion(nil, err)
            return
        }
        do {
            let objects = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!)
            // success
            completion(objects, nil)
        } catch {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
        }.resume()
}

func fetchHomeFeed(completion: @escaping (OrderRawData?, Error?) -> ()) {
    let urlString = "url.com"
    fetchJSON(urlString: urlString, completion: completion)
}
```

So I call `fetchHomeFeed` from my `HomeControllerView`, nothing fancy there.

When I test API in Postman, I get response in less than 300ms. And in android there is no problem like this.

Is there any way to know what the problem is? FYI, I use Hostinger.

Comment: These are usually known as [cold starts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_start_(computing)). Basically, if you haven't used the API in a while, it may take slightly longer to fulfil your request. When the API receives higher demand it shouldn't cold start.

Comment: So, does it mean once the app is deployed and people start using it regularly there won't be this kind of problem?

Comment: Exactly, if you have consistent calls to the API, it will stay ready and doesn’t need to wait to spin-up.

Comment: to add to what @George said, as a test/confirmation try to contact your API first from outside of the mobile app (e.g. from browser or playground), and then try to reproduce a slow first request. If you can't, the cold start is to blame.